# override the PowerShell Cmdlet approach and have a PowerShell script manually process flags?

Tags: powershell

Is there away to override the PowerShell Cmdlet approach and have a PowerShell script manually process Script Arguments?

I Just want a simple example of a Powershell script that uses the classic C/perl approach of using "GetOptions" to process script argument flags manually.  Instead of breaking everything up into "Command-lets", since in my case I don't care about integrating my script with the shell and returning objects for other command-let etc...  Its just a one time use case where classic approach would be better than command-lets...

Comment: "since in my case I don't care about integrating my script with the shell and returning objects for other command-let" - then why use PowerShell at all? :)

Comment: because I need to use Powershell to  run some Git Bash scripts using Powershell "Invoke-Command"

Comment: Well, the reason there isn't a readily available `getoptions()` in PowerShell is because PowerShell already has a syntactic cognate - the `param()` block. Check out the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters)

Comment: There's also `$Args`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

File: script.ps1

```
param ($servername, $envname='Odyessy')

if ($servername -eq $null) {
    $servername = read-host -Prompt "Please enter a servername" 
}

write-host "If this script were really going to do something, it would do it on $servername in the $envname environment"
```

Example:

```
.\script.ps1 -servername HAL 
.\script.ps1 -envname Discovery
```

Also See:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/

Comment: I see no benefit in going low-level like this. No need for `read-host` etc., in Powershell, you'd just make the parameter "Mandatory", and PowerShell will do this "read-host" logic for you.

Comment: I didn't write the code... its from the website i quoted.  Its just a demonstration if you wanted to override the normal param behavior.